# Elastic Search Client Is appending a type to the rest endpoint

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Stack:
Elastic Search 7.8.0,
Spring Data Elastic Search 3.1.12.RELEASE (later versions not supported by 7.8.0),
ES Rest Client ( 7.17.8, obtained transitively from spring data elastic search above.

I'm using Elastic Search repositories and the document mapping is as below:

```
@Document(indexName = "items*", createIndex = false)
public class LineItem{

//the fields

}
```

Then I use a multi-field query that spans all indexes that start with items* ( as per above mapping ). Spring fires a query to http://eshost:9200/items*/**lineitem**/_search. The query is correct but because it appends the type field (which is the name of the class = lineitem), I don't find any hits for this. Why is it appending a type to the endpoint and how do I avoid this as I don't really need the type? I get the hits when I remove the lineitem text from the endpoint path.

Answer (score 0):

It makes me wonder how you get Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.1.12 to use the REST interface to talk to Elasticsearch. Support for the REST interface was added in Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2, before that the transport interface was used.

Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.1.12.RELEASE is a pretty outdated version from November 2019 and was built with the Elasticsearch library version 6.2.2.

Even version 3.2.x, that introduced support for the REST client, was using Elasticsearch libraries in version 6.8, and in that version the type parameter was still in use; we removed it when starting to build with Elasticsearch 7.

Looking at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions I'd say that at least Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0 if not 4.1 should work with an Elasticsearch server 7.8.

btw, Elasticsearch 7.8.0 is quite outdated as well, it was released in June 2020.